# D3, get X values (date) from multiple Y values, create text

Tags: d3.js

I have searched through many answers about getting X (date) values given a Y. Most revolve around the scale.invert() function. However, I am having trouble implementing this in my task.

**Task:** I am creating a hydrograph (time-series line graph of water level). I'm also plotting min/max points, and median line, all with text labels. See first image. This is a 'proof of concept', so I'm ok with things being a little dirty.

**Problem:** I want to add the corresponding dates for those min/max points, and I can't figure out how. One caveat, sometimes there are multiple points with same min or max value. I am unable to: **A)** get the correct date for the point, and **B)** add the date for each instance (all mins and maxes, if there are multiples) to the text.  Thanks for any help or direction.

Some of the code (that I think is immediately relevant) is below. [Here's the codepen](http://codepen.io/tangnar123/pen/pjyvVV). I'm sure it's not pretty, I'm new to D3 and javascript.

[image: hydrograph]

```
...

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Water Level (ft)");

    svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);

    var extent = d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.level
    })
    var min = extent[0]
    var max = extent[1]
    var median = d3.median(data, function(d) {
      return d.level
    })

    var medianLine = svg.append("line")
      .attr("class", "medianLine")
      .attr("y1", y(median))
      .attr("y2", y(median))
      .attr("x1", 0)
      .attr("x2", width)

    var points = svg.selectAll("g")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .filter(function(d) {
        return d.level === min || d.level === max;
      })
    points.append("circle")
      .attr("class", "dot")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return y(d.level);
      })
      .attr("r", 5)
    points.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
      .attr("y", -20)
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", "12px")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    points.selectAll("circle")
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        if (d.level === min) {
          return "red"
        } else {
          return "#009933"
        };
      });
    points.selectAll("text")
      .text(function(d) {
        if (d.level === min) {
          return "Min: " + min
        } else if (d.level === max) {
          return "Max: " + max
        }
      })
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        if (d.level === min) {
          return "red"
        } else if (d.level === max) {
          return "#246B24"
        }
      })
    svg.append("text")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width + 3) + "," + y(median) + ")")
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "start")
      .style("fill", "#cc6600")
      .text(function(d) {
        return "Median: " + median
      })

...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a quick peek to the code the `date` is a property of your data so there should not be any problem accessing it e.g.

```
points.selectAll("text")
  .text(function(d) {
    // date is accessible through d.date
    if (d.level === min) {
      return "Min: " + min + ' ' + d.date
    } else if (d.level === max) {
      return "Max: " + max + ' ' + d.date
    }
  })
```

If you want to format the date you can read [about time formatting in d3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting)

Comment: Wow, so simple, I was definitely over thinking this.  Thank you.